# What is the opposite word of “spoiled”? As in “spoiled child”

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, I want to describe the “opposite of spoiled’ child who’s been beaten by their parents, never gets allowance or rewards or gifts even for hard work.

A few words that come to mind but don’t really fit perfectly:
*forlorn, deficient, inadequate, pitiable, paltry*.

A sentence where this word would be used:

> Person A: "You're a spoiled child with a nice house and relatively middle class."
>   Person B: "I might have many physical gifts, but I'm not spoiled emotionally. In fact, I'm a [**insert word**/neglected/doormat/scorned/ignored] child when it comes to love. My parents tell me I'm worthless, everything is my fault, I'm bad at everything I do, and that they wish they were dead because of me."
>   Person A: "Oh, I see... sorry for the judgment."

Comment: Please supply a sentence where this word would be used. A child that is physically beaten is not the opposite of a spoiled child, IMO that would be a child that is not treated differently to their peers, a child without special privileges or concessions. I might argue that "well-balanced" is the opposite of spoiled. But it does not describe a child physically punished, and one who is basically unloved.

Comment: I think **doormat** can be a suitable word for a child who is treated in such way. See this link for the meaning of doormat: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doormat

Comment: Edited question to include a sample sentence. Thanks

Comment: Doormat is a noun.it can not be used as an adjective.you can say 'I am a doormat' but you can't say 'I am a doormat child

Comment: Being middle-class doesn't define a spoiled child, so A is using the expression incorrectly. They  think B is _privileged_. A _spoiled_ child is one who has been given anything they asked for even if it was bad for them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a child that has been under constant abuse by his or her parents, technically speaking, could be called **an abused child**.

Comment: I'm surprised you thought of "constant abuse" when thinking of the opposite of spoiled. If spoiled means having everything one wants and has all their demands met, the opposite hardly would seem to me to be "constant abuse" or abused child. Yet weirdly your answer is the only one upvoted, so maybe I'm crazy.

Comment: @Zebrafish I think it's because the OP used the example of a child who is beaten in their question.

Comment: @Tom Ah, I see that.

Comment: I was the first to suggest the word "abused" (and "neglected", "scorned" and "ignored") before user69786 posted, but my answer was later deleted and actually downvoted apparently for not putting it in a sentence. I think it's an excellent answer to the question. If the admins determined the OP needs to rework their question, I'm not sure why I got penalized.